# From where does the compiler start reading

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is a small program :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    f();
    system("pause");
}

void f() {
    static int x = 20 ;
    class tester {
    public :
        tester() {
            cout << x ;
        }
    } x1;
}
```

The error that i get here is :**error C3861: 'f': identifier not found**

If i place the function `f` above main I will get the desired output.

**Why it is so ?** 
I was told that program execution begins at `main`. According to this the code should run in the first case also.

**How does the compiler start reading the program?**

Comment: from top to bottom, and your f() is at the bottom, of course it doesn't see it

Comment: @vBx You say that like all languages require definition before reference. Go write this in Python and see what happens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The beginning of the compilation and the beginning of the execution of the program are two different things.

The execution starts from the `main`.

The compilation begins from the beginning of the file; the compiler don't "jump around" the file to find the needed pieces, but it reads the input in a linear fashion (I suspect that this related, among the other things, to the fact that the C++ grammar is really complicated).

When the compiler is at some point in parsing the file, it only knows what has been declared/defined up to that point<sup>1</sup>.

Because of this, *function prototypes* (and non-defining declarations in general) have been invented: the prototypes of all the functions *defined* in the file are put at the beginning of the file, typically after the `#include` directives or in a separated include file. The prototypes tell to the compiler that such functions will be defined later, and what is the function signature (i.e. name, parameters, return value).

The prototype is made as a normal function, but without the body, which is replaced by a semicolon<sup>2</sup>. For example, in your code you would write

```
void f();
```

before the `main`.

---

1. IIRC there are some relaxations to this rule that allow the compiler to "wait" for some declarations to make some template magic work, but this is not relevant here.
2. In a prototype is also common not to write the names of the parameters, leaving just their type (this can be done also in function definitions, but it doesn't make much sense there unless you have a formal parameter you don't use). Still, I prefer to leave the parameter names there as a form of documentation.

Comment: Your point 2 is somewhat misleading; in a function definition you are equally allowed to omit the names of parameters. Obviously you can't refer to an unnamed parameter, and therefore can't use its value.

Comment: @MSalters: didn't know about that, I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 7):

> I was told that program execution begins at main.

And that's exactly the point.

The compiler starts from `main`, and then sees a call to `f()`, which it has not encountered so far (as it is defined afterwards), so it does not know what to do with it.

If you want to define `f` after `main` you can place a function prototype before, such as

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(); // <--- This tells the compiler that a function name f will be defined

int main() {
f();
system("pause");
}

void f() {
static int x = 20 ;
class tester {
public :
    tester() {
        cout << x ;
    }
} x1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To be able to call a function it must have been declared at some earlier point in the code. This is just a rule of the language designed to help compilers.

You can *declare* the function earlier with e.g.

```
void f();
```

...and then *define* it after main as you have done.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler starts at the top and reads down to the bottom.

you'll need to have something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f();

int main() {
f();
system("pause");
}

void f() {
static int x = 20 ;
class tester {
public :
    tester() {
        cout << x ;
    }
} x1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the compiler needs to see at least a declaration of f() before it is used. A c(++) code file is a simple text file and must be read from begin to end by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

During the compilation process, when the compiler is evaluating `main()` it needs to know what `f()` is in advance to be able to generate the correct assembly code to call this function. That's why you need to put it before `main()` in this case.

As an alternative you can declare the prototype of `f()` before `main()` so the compiler knows it's a local function declared somewhere else on your file:

```
void f(); // prototype

int main() 
{
  // .. code ..
}

void f() // implementation of f()
{
 // .. code ..
}
```