# Why use function-declarations in C?

Tags: c

Why does C have *function declarations*?

Example from *C in a Nutshell*:

```
//circle.c: Calculate and print the areas of circles

#include <stdio.h>

double circularArea( double r );

int main()
{
    double radius = 1.0, area = 0.0;
    printf( "     Areas of Circle\n\n" );
    printf( "      radius         Area\n"
            "-------------------------\n" );

    area = circularArea( radius );
    printf( "%10.1f     %10.2f\n", radius, area );

    radius = 5.0;
    area = circularArea( radius );
    printf( "%10.1f     %10.2f\n", radius, area );

    return 0;
}

double circularArea( double r )
{
    const double pi = 3.14159265;
    return pi * r * r;
}
```

What is the purpose of typing "double circularArea( double r );" on the 5th line?

Comment: the purpose of the prototypes is so, at the call to the function, the compiler knows the parameter type(s) and the return type.  Earlier versions of C would make the assumption of all such items being 'int'.  Later versions of C will raise a compile warning/error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C compiler processes a source file from top to bottom. When it encounters a use of a function, it needs to know the arguments and return types of the function. You either have to declare or define the function before you use it, so it knows these types.

So you can either move the definition of `curcularArea` to before `main()`, or you can put a declaration before `main()`.

A common style is to put declarations of all functions at the beginning of the file. Then you can define all your functions in any order, rather than having to worry about which calls which so you put all the dependencies first. Also, if you have mutually-recursive functions, no ordering of the definitions will work, you'll need a declaration of one of them.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So the compiler must know that is "exists" and is defined after main{}. This might be useful then if I want main{} to appear at the top of the program? And if I don't mind where it is, at the bottom say, I could just define all of the functions before main{} and then call them in main{}?

Comment: I just added another paragraph addressing that.

Comment: This seems a lot better than Python actually, because I've noticed it's a bit of a pain to have to worry about the ordering of my function declarations etc.

Comment: @Barmar "The C compiler processes a source file from bottom to top" i think you made a typo! Otherwise see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6493958/3933332

Comment: "The general convention..." actually, it isn't. Follow DRY and just define them before you use them.

Comment: @Deduplicator Many programmers like to put the `main()` function first. And you can't do that for functions that call each other.

Comment: Meh.  The `main()` function can go anywhere.  If it means I don't have to needlessly duplicate function declarations, hell yes; I'll put it at the end.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've changed my answer to say "common style" rather than "general convention". Good enough for you?

Comment: Sure, why not?  Popularity is as good a metric as any for making a programming decision.

Comment: If you have to define everything before you use it, you have to keep track of which functions use each other function, to ensure the proper ordering. Declaring everything up front is simpler.

Comment: Or, y'know, you can just put your needed functions (in their entirety) at the top, and `main()` at the bottom.

Comment: `main()` isn't the only function that calls other functions, you know. Every time you define another function, you have to ensure that it's located before all the functions that call it, and after all the functions that it calls.

Comment: @Barmar: `main()` might not be the only one calling other functions, but it certainly won't be called by your own code. And if you don't know what calls/needs what, you are in trouble anyway.

Comment: The point is that it's a maintenance headache trying to keep everything in the proper order as you define new functions. Declaring everything first is a simple rule that avoids that problem.

Comment: @Barmar: I disagree. The duplication is the maintenance nightmare there.

Answer (score 2):

The Compiler goes from the `top` to the `bottom`! So if your calling a `function` in `main` which is at this time `not declared` it's `undefined`! So that this error don't appear you make a `declaration` at the `top` to say the compiler hey the function comes after the main, but it's there!

Comment: What if I define the function before main()?

Comment: @bd1251252 Yes thats a good question ;) then you don't have to make such a declaration, because at the call of the function it's already knowen! Just play around with this an test it! copy your function above main and delete the forward declaration

Answer (score 0):

The compiler goes line by line. Without the declaration, when the compiler encountered the use of `circularArea` within the `main()` function, it would not know what that was an error. The declaration is basically a promise to the compiler that you will define a function with that signature later.

Answer (score 0):

C is inherently single-pass, which means you cannot use symbols (variables, macros, functions) before they are made known to the compiler.

Declarations make a symbol known to the compiler and usable in the translation unit (file) thence onward.

Those declarations are collected in header-files to avoid errors on re-writing them and to facilitate re-use and separate compilation.

Local symbols are introduced with declarations before the first point of use to allow recursive referencing between multiple symbols.
Those declarations are known as forward-declarations.

While one can use forward-declarations without need, an easier solution avoiding duplication is just moving the function-definition before the first point of use, because a definition is also a declaration.